Advice on Keeping Directories Synced Between Two Linux Laptops?
I need advice about syncing directories between two Linux laptops. Currently, I'm using Google Drive mounted with google-drive-ocamlfuse on both machines, but it's causing significant performance issues. Basic operations like cp, mv, and even compilation are running very slowly.
What I'm specifically looking for is a setup where each laptop maintains its own local copy of the data, with a master copy on a cloud/NFS server. The ideal tool would automatically sync changes made on either laptop with the master copy and update accordingly.
Any suggestions for a better solution would be appreciated

This question is similar to: Sync a folder between 2 computers, with a filesystem watcher so that each time a file is modified, it is immediately replicated. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Dropbox does it for me. www.dropbox.com When I add a file to a shared folder, the dropboxd daemon schedules an upload. When the upload is complete, the next time dropboxd on my other systems connect, they make the file appear in their shared directories. Warning: my configuration costs me money, an annual $ubscription.
